# Is there any way to mount my local HDD/SSD to use with Google Colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Colaboratory allows to mount Google Drive and use data from Drive but I have massive datasets (including images) on my local system that would take a long time and huge space on drive.
So, I am looking for something similar but here I want to mount my local system's Drive.

Answer (score -2):

One option is to run Jupyter locally and connect to it using Colab, thereby providing the benefits of Drive storage and sharing for your notebooks, but allowing easy access to local files.

Instructions are here: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Comment: I guess this mean the notebook will be running on your local CPU without the benefit of a cloud GPU?